# jQuery - toggle different classes one time at each

Tags: javascript, jquery

First I'd like to apologize because my code layout isn't the best. What I'm trying to accomplish here is to display a description of a text sample by pressing an info button.  My problem is when I press any of the info buttons, it displays all the descriptions of all text samples, when it should show only the description of the intended text sample at each time.

I appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("dd").hide();
                $(".btn1").click(function() {
                    $("dd").toggle("slow");
                });
                $("dd").hide();
                $(".btn2").click(function() {
                    $("dd").toggle("slow");
                });
                $("dd").hide();
                $(".btn3").click(function() {
                    $("dd").toggle("slow");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <dl>
            <dt>Coffee</dt>
            <button class="btn1">+ Info</button>
            <dd>Black hot drink</dd>
            <dt>Milk</dt>
            <button class="btn2">+ Info</button>
            <dd>White cold drink</dd>
            <dt>Water</dt>
            <button class="btn3">+ Info</button>
            <dd>Transparent fluid</dd>
        </dl> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - "New" tags? user3163835 - dl elements aren't supposed to directly contain anything but dt and dd elements (so you shouldn't have button elements unless they're inside the dt elements, though as usual browsers are fairly forgiving about that sort of thing).

Comment: @nnnnnn - Oh wait you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your html into the following adding IDs to the dd :

```
<body>
        <dl>
            <dt>Coffee</dt>
            <button class="btn1">+ Info</button>
            <dd id="dd1">Black hot drink</dd>
            <dt>Milk</dt>
            <button class="btn2">+ Info</button>
            <dd id="dd2">White cold drink</dd>
            <dt>Water</dt>
            <button class="btn3">+ Info</button>
            <dd id="dd3">Transparent fluid</dd>
        </dl> 
    </body>
```

Then in your jquery script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("dd").hide();
            $(".btn1").click(function() {
                $("#dd1").toggle("slow");
            });
            $("dd").hide();
            $(".btn2").click(function() {
                $("#dd2").toggle("slow");
            });
            $("dd").hide();
            $(".btn3").click(function() {
                $("#dd3").toggle("slow");
            });
        });
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QmbtT/)

**EDIT  :**

Here is a shorter version of the above code achieving the same result in less code lines:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("dd").hide();
   $("dl button").click(function() {
     $("dd").hide();

     var number = $(this).attr('class').substr(-1);
     $("#dd"+number).toggle("slow");
   });           
});
```

Comment: Why would you change the html and repeat the same code for different ids when you can do the whole thing with [three lines of code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20941462/615754) that work on the existing html? [Don't repeat yourself.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Comment: well actually when i was writting this answer didnt check the above which is obviously better:)

Comment: I had to change my html a bit but I got it working thanks to you. I appreciate your help on this matter.

Comment: Glad i was able to help you :)

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
$(".btn1").click(function(){
    $("dd").toggle("slow");
 });
```

To

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $(this).next('dd').toggle("slow");
});
```

Because you need to select not ALL dd elements, but only the ones that are next to the button that was clicked.